# sync independet callbacks result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronization, promise

I am searching for an elegant way to sync indepentent callbacks result invoked in unknown order.

```
function callback1() {
  var result;
};
function callback2() {
  var result;
};

//When done then call
function success(res1, res2) {
  // do whatever
}
```

I know I can do something like:

```
var res = {};
var dfd = $.Deferred();
function callback1() {
  var result;
  res.res1 = result;
  (res.res1 && res.res2) && (dfd.resolve(res));
};

function callback1() {
  var result;
  res.res2 = result;
  (res.res1 && res.res2) && (dfd.resolve(res));
};

dfd.done(function(result){
  // do whatever
});
```

but I would appreciate if somebody comes up with more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

If you return promises (builtin promises, not jQuery deferreds) and you don't care about order, then you can use `Promise.all`:

```
function callback1() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

function callback2() {
  return Promise.resolve(2)
}

var ps = [callback1(), callback2()]

function add(x, y) {
  return x + y
}

Promise.all(ps).then(function(result) {
  return result.reduce(add)
}).then(console.log) // => 3
```

If you want to sequence them you can do it in such a way that you can apply a curried function that expects as many arguments as resolved promises there are by lifting it into the promise world. In other words:

```
function apply(pa, pf) {
  return pf.then(function(f) {
    return pa.then(f)
  })
}

function lift(f, ps) {
  return ps.reduce(function(pa, pb) {
    return apply(pb, pa)
  }, Promise.resolve(f))
}

function add(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y
  }
}

lift(add, ps).then(console.log) //=> 3
```

You can also sequence them in such a way that you don't need a curried function, by collecting the results in an array first then reducing it:

```
function sequence(ps) {
  return ps.reduceRight(function(pa, pb) {
    return pa.then(function(a) {
      return pb.then(function(b) {
        return [b].concat(a)
      })
    })
  }, Promise.resolve([]))
}

function add(x, y) {
  return x + y
}

// This looks similar to the Promise.all approach
// but they run in order
sequence(ps).then(function(result) {
  return result.reduce(add)
}).then(console.log) // => 3
```

Comment: 10x very interresting and elegant, unfortunely this isn't cross browser and I can not use it althoug i would like to. :(

Comment: It is crossbrowser, if you need to suppprt old IE just include a promise polyfill and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that do this, such as the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, but here's a "from scratch" solution. I'm also avoiding promises to avoid overwhelming you, but you should really read about them as they are the most elegant solution, albeit complicated for first timers.

```
function runInParallel(jobs, done) {
  // Store all our results in an array.
  var results = [];
  // If one job fails, set this to true and use it to
  // ignore all job results that follow.
  var failureOccurred = false;
  // Iterate over each of our registered jobs.
  jobs.forEach(function (runJob, index) {
    // Create a jobDone callback to pass to the job.
    var jobDone = function (err, result) {
      // If another job failed previously, abort processing
      // this job's result. We no longer care.
      if (failureOccurred) return;
      // If this job passed in an error, set failure to true
      // and pass the error to the final done callback.
      if (err) {
        failureOccurred = true;
        done(err);
        return;
      }
      // If we made it this far then push the job result into
      // the results array at the same position as the job in
      // the jobs array.
      results[index] = result;
      // If the results array contains as many results as the
      // jobs array had jobs then we have finished processing
      // them all. Invoke our done callback with an array of
      // all results.
      if (results.length === jobs.length) {
        done(null, results);
      }
    };
    // Begin the job and pass in our jobDone callback.
    runJob(jobDone);
  });
}
```

This will call all of your job functions in the array, passing in a `jobDone` callback the job should call when finished. If any job passes an error in then the function will immediately invoke the result callback with the error and ignore everything else. If the jobs succeed then you'll end up with an array of job results in the same positions as the jobs were in the jobs array. Simply modify your job functions to accept the `jobDone` callback.

```
var jobs = [
  function job1(done) {
    try {
      var result;
      done(null, result);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  },
  function job2(done) {
    try {
      var result;
      done(null, result);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  }
];

runInParallel(jobs, function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  // results[0] = jobs[0] result
  // results[1] = jobs[1] result
  // etc...
});
```

Instead of an array of jobs you could modify this code to accept an object with property names. Then instead of assigning the results to the same position as the jobs in the jobs array you could assign the results to an object using the same property names.

Example (without comments this time):

```
function runInParallel(jobs, done) {
  var results = {};
  var failureOccurred = false;
  Object.keys(jobs).forEach(function (jobName) {
    var jobDone = function (err, result) {
      if (failureOccurred) return;
      if (err) {
        failureOccurred = true;
        done(err);
        return;
      }
      results[jobName] = result;
      if (results.length === jobs.length) {
        done(null, results);
      }
    };
    jobs[jobName](jobDone);
  });
}
```

Then you can consume it like this:

```
var jobs = {
  job1: function (done) {
    try {
      var result;
      done(null, result);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  },
  job2: function (done) {
    try {
      var result;
      done(null, result);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  }
};

runInParallel(jobs, function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  // results.job1 = job1 result
  // results.job2 = job2 result
  // etc...
});
```

The [parallel function](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) in the async library does almost exactly what we've done above. It even accepts an array of jobs or an object of named jobs like we did :)

Comment: I can only define and subscribe to the callbacks(jobs) invokeing I don't controll it :(
I can't run them in parallel

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tasks (`callback1()` and `callback2()`) are *synchronous*, you might choose to write a reusable generalisation of the code in the question, in the form of a function that returns a function, trapping a couple of private vars in a closure :

```
function resultAggregator(n, fn) {
    var results = {},
        count = 0;
    return function(id, res) {
        count++;
        results[id] = res;
        if (count == n) {
            fn(results);
        }
    }
}
```

So after calling `resultAccumulator()`, you have a function that can kept in-scope of other functions or passed to other parts of your code base. It makes no assumptions about ids or the nature of the results, except that they are synchronously derived. It will fire its callback when `n` results have been delivered.

```
var myResults = resultAggregator(2, function(results) {
    // do whatever;
});

//The following commands may be in different parts of your code base
myResults('id1', synchTask1());
...
myResults('id2', synchTask2());
...
myResults('id3', synchTask3());

//The second tasks to deliver its data (ostensibly `synchTask1()` and `synchTask2()`, but not necessarily) will trigger the callback.
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/02tum4yy/2/)**

This is just one way to perform result aggregation. You might do something different depending on the exact scenario. Here's a slightly different formulation which records the order in which the results arrived :

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/02tum4yy/3/)**

Whatever you write, Deferreds/Promises are not necessary for the aggregation of synchronously derived data.

However, if any one task is, or may be, asynchronous then you may need a promise aggregator, eg `jQuery.when()` or `Promise.all()`, somewhere in the pattern.